# Error in ownCloud client on changing the DocumentRoot in WAMP

Tags: localhost, wamp, wampserver, owncloud

I am facing a problem when I changed the

> Documentroot from "//wamp/www/"

to

> "wamp/www/owncloud"

, the ownCloud client software on the computer stopped working. This is the error being given

> "Unable to connect to http://localhost/owncloud ; Error Downloading
>   http://localhost/owncloud/status.php - server replied; Not found."

I am doing this so that I can open my ownCloud page directly on writing the IP address of the computer or by writing localhost.

I think I have tried to get my point across. Please let me know if any more info. is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If as you say you have changed the `DocumentRoot` to point to `\wamp\www\owncloud` then that also means you have made locahost point to `\wamp\www\owncloud`

So just use `http://localhost` and it will launch index.php from the `\wamp\www\owncloud\index.php`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying! It was because of me altering the code! Its working fine now! Thanks again!!